# Unable to add automatic "next slide" to my image slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am unable to add a automatic function that shows the next image in my slideshow. I have tried different approaches i found on this forum using setinterval() alas to no success.

Here is a snippet of the JS code.

```
const pizzaSlide = document.querySelector(".pizza-slide");
const pizzaImages = document.querySelectorAll(".pizza-slide img");   //Selector for all images

//Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");


//Counter - To figure out what image we are on we need a counter.
let counter = 1;    //Starting from the first image
const size = pizzaImages[0].clientWidth;    //Width of the image, so we know how much we need to slide.

pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter ) + "px)";    //Moves one picture forward

//Timer
let timer = setInterval(() => pluscounter(1), 1000); - does not work.

//Button Listeners

nextBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{  //Listens on click - adds transition
    if(counter >= pizzaImages.length -1) return;     //This is to prevent slideshow bugging out if nextBtn is clicked too fast.
    pizzaSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";     // The speed of the transitions.
    counter++; //Adds one to counter
    pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter ) + "px)"; 
    setInterval(nextBtn, 500);
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{ //Listens on click - adds transition
    if (counter <= 0) return;   //This is to prevent slideshow bugging out if prevBtn is clicked too fast.
    pizzaSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";     // The speed of the transitions.
    counter--; //Retracts one from counter
    pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter ) + "px)";
});

pizzaSlide.addEventListener("transitionend", ()=>{  //Returns back to original image after the transform finishes - resets the transition if the picture is a "clone".
    if(pizzaImages[counter].id === "lastClone"){
        pizzaSlide.style.transition = "none";   //Translates it back to original picture
        counter = pizzaImages.length -2;
        pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter ) + "px)";
    }
    if(pizzaImages[counter].id === "firstClone"){
        pizzaSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = pizzaImages.length - counter;    //Translates it back to original picture
        pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter ) + "px)";
    }
});
```

Update1
CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pizza-container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: relative;
}

.pizza-slide {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
} 


#prevBtn, #nextBtn {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #444444;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#prevBtn{
    left: 5%;
}

#nextBtn{
    right: 5%;
}

#prevBtn:hover, #nextBtn:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    background-color: #29a8e2;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>slideshow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pizza-container">
         <!-- slider controls -->
         <div id="prevBtn"><</div>
         <div id="nextBtn">></div>
         <!-- slider controls -->
        <div class="pizza-slide">
            <img src="./img/bilde3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
            <img src="./img/bilde4.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/bilde2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/bilde3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/bilde4.jpg"  id="firstClone" alt="">
            <!-- to get a smooth infinite loop we need to clone the last and first image-->
        </div>
      
    </div>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

IGNORE THIS
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: where is pluscounter(1) function located?

Comment: @Celadon you really need to provide a more-complete code example. This fragment just isn't enough to see what's going on. Please add a working example (including the css).

Comment: The above JS is not really a snippet it's all of the JS code. It works flawlessly using the buttons but i want it also to automatically change image without interaction.

There are not enough characters to show the CSS, but its only used for styling the box the images are located in and the arrows used for navigating.

Comment: I assumme pluscounter(1) is similar to my counter++ under prevBtn.addEventListener?

Comment: If you post the code as a snippet, you're able to insert the code for html, css and javascript individually. At least we'd need to see the html.

Comment: @obscure I have now added an update to the original post with the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

The manual and your desired automatic control of the slideshow have one thing in common: both do the same thing! So instead of adding anonymous functions to the click event listeners of your buttons, let's make a function that can be called manually and automatically. In 'automatic mode' I'd rather use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` though. This way the function calls itself again periodically and resets the timer to the desired interval if the user pressed on one of the navigation buttons.

There's just one more problem with your code:

```
const size = pizzaImages[0].clientWidth;
```

this line gives **size** the value of whatever the first `<img>` element's width in your `<div>` is - which can also mean it might be 0 as the image might not be loaded yet. So let's make sure it finished loading and afterwards populate size with the correct size. Additionally this would be the perfect time to start automatic playback of your slideshow.

```
pizzaImages[0].addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  size = e.target.clientWidth;
  timer = setTimeout(nextPressed, 1500);
});
```

Here's the complete working example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
const pizzaSlide = document.querySelector(".pizza-slide");
const pizzaImages = document.querySelectorAll(".pizza-slide img");

const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");

let counter = 0;
let size;
let timer;

pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";

function nextPressed() {
  if (counter >= pizzaImages.length - 1) return;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(nextPressed, 1500);
  pizzaSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
  counter++;
  pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
}

function prevPressed() {
  if (counter <= 0) return;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(prevPressed, 1500);
  pizzaSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
  counter--;
  pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextPressed);
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", prevPressed);

pizzaSlide.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
  if (pizzaImages[counter].id === "lastClone") {
    pizzaSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = pizzaImages.length - 2;
    pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
  }
  if (pizzaImages[counter].id === "firstClone") {
    pizzaSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = 1;
    pizzaSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size * counter) + "px)";
  }
});

pizzaImages[0].addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  size = e.target.clientWidth;
  timer = setTimeout(nextPressed, 1500);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pizza-container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.pizza-slide {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#prevBtn,
#nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #444444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#prevBtn {
  left: 5%;
}

#nextBtn {
  right: 5%;
}

#prevBtn:hover,
#nextBtn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  background-color: #29a8e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pizza-container">
  <!-- slider controls -->
  <div id="prevBtn">
    <</div>
      <div id="nextBtn">></div>
      <!-- slider controls -->
      <div class="pizza-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" id="firstClone" alt="">
        <!-- to get a smooth infinite loop we need to clone the last and first image-->
      </div>

  </div>
```